# VBA - copy text from website and added into word template

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, ms-word

I'm trying to copy data from several IE pages containing contact info for some persons and then add it into a word template using VBA and word content control This needs to be done dynamically country of origin can be different.
The HMTL source code from where I would like to extract the data looks like:

```
<td rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
  Mrs Mallet Anonime
  <br></br>
  11, RUE FRANCOIS BOLLE
  <br></br>
  12345 PARIS 05 FRANCE
  <br></br>
</td>
```

As I'm using a word template to do this the writing needs to look in the following order as in a letter:

> Mrs Mallet Anonime
>
> 11, RUE FRANCOIS BOLLE
>
> 12345 PARIS 05
>
> FRANCE

Unfortunately the country may not be same for all of these letters (ENGLAND,SWITZERLAND,etc.).Any ideas how to proceed with this??

Answer (score 0):

First, look how the general stuff works. Searchbar: `VBA IE automation`

The try

```
'First, create an object "ie" and use "ie.navigate" to get to your website. Then:

dim td_col as iHTMLElementCollection
dim td_elem as iHTMLElement

set td_col = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")
for each td_elem in td_col
    Word.Selection.TypeText (vbCrLf + td_elem.innertext)
Next td_elem
```

Hope that helps.